# Is my question too subjective?

Tags: discussion

My recent [Do the internal inconsistencies of Futurama ever cause it to suffer?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/18592/do-the-internal-inconsistencies-of-futurama-ever-cause-it-to-suffern) question has been called subjective. How can I fix it, if it indeed needs fixing?

Answer (score 2):

It certainly doesn't look subjective to me. Your question is asking two distinct, independently verifiable things:

1. Has the Futurama fandom ever reacted negatively to one of its many consistency hiccups?
2. Was there ever a retcon of a consistency error with the purpose of placating an angry fanbase?

These two basic questions seem to me to be fairly straightforward yes/no questions. Either there were problems or there weren't, either they led to retcons or they didn't.

You're not appealing to individual opinions here, but to a community's reaction, which is something that can be objectively measured.

Comment: I think you've put it better than I could have. Mind if I pinch your phrasing?

Comment: Oh, not at all. :)

Comment: I believe frustration in this type of question is caused by a generally accepted "source gap". Since Futurama never appeared to suffer at the hands of anything, it stands that it did not suffer as a result of a poor continuity choice. The reason for any incontinuity therefore can not be accredited to a reaction following negative ratings. ...however, it does not bar the possibility that there was some sort of un-published strife, by which a writer may have taken influence from.  This makes for unsatisfying answers that can legitimately be left open, waiting for info that isn't available yet.

Comment: Regardless, we cannot start basing a questions validity on whether the answer is available or not. That puts an unreasonable onus on the asker to answer his own question before asking it. The question *is not* subjective, and *is* perfectly valid.